# How to keep all commit history in an old repo and move its content into a new one if the old repository doesn't exist online?

Tags: git, github

the situation is that I have a local copy of one repository which has all commit history in its git log. It was the course repository that I used for last semester, and now the instructor has cleaned up that repository online - so it only exists on my computer.

I would love to keep all the commit history and move its content to a new repo. However, when I try to push remotely Git raised the error of cannot read from remote repository.

In this case, what can I do to keep the git log and move all contents to a newly-created repo?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change the origin of your repo to the new location: https://www.ethode.com/blog/git-change-remote-origin

With that everything including the git log will be pushed to the new location.

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repositoryName.git
$ git config master.remote origin
$ git config master.merge refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Many thanks! I also found it useful by directly editing the repository url in config file located at .git folder.